# Using Cut with Fast Seek -ss -to and HH:MM:SS:MS

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to cut a video using `-ss` and `-to` using `HH:MM:SS:MS` time.

I'm using `-to` instead of `-t` because I want the cut to be "between" a time range and not "up to" time.
I also have to use `-to` because it's needed for another program's time input textbox I'm using. I won't be able to use `-t` for this case.

Example:

https://superuser.com/a/670590

`-ss 00:01:00:00 -to 00:02:00:00` cut starts at minute 1, ends at minute 2.
`-ss 00:01:00:00 -t 00:02:00:00` cut starts at minute 1, ends at minute 3.

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Seeking#Cuttingsmallsections

---

#### Problem

I'm not able to use Fast Seek, `-ss` before the `-i`, `-to` after.

I'm only able to use Slow Seek, `-ss` and `-to` after the `-i`.

---

#### 1. Fast

**Doesn't Work**

This cuts a minute ahead of what's in the time.

Cuts from `00:01:00` to `00:03:00`, using the `faster` seek.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy cut.mp4
```

---

#### 2. Slow

**Works**

I'm trying to do this but with fast seek.

Cuts from `00:01:00` to `00:02:00`, using the `slower` seek.

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -c copy cut.mp4
```

---

#### 3. Fast

**Works (with problems)**

`-copyts` ruins video time bar in player.

Cuts from `00:01:00` to `00:02:00`, using the `faster` seek.

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy -copyts cut.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remux the result of method 3

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -i video.mp4 -to 00:02:00 -c copy -copyts cut.mp4
```

&&

```
ffmpeg -i cut.mp4 -c copy recut.mp4
```

or with a recent version of ffmpeg,

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:00 -to 00:02:00 -i video.mp4 -c copy cut.mp4
```

Comment: Looks like that works, thanks. I thought I tried that before and it didn't work, but it's because I wasn't using codec `copy`. Do you also know how fast seek with `-to` can be used when `encoding` instead of `copy`? When I put the time before the `-i`, it ignores the end time and keeps going.

Comment: It should make no difference. Share full command + log of this attempt.

Comment: Can't deal with this. When I use some filters they are omitted.